# Unusual Lemo PCB sockets (male PCB contacts, 2-pin 5B, etc)

Tags: pcb, connector, datasheet

I am trying to construct a comprehensive Kicad library of Lemo connectors. While working through the "normal" datasheet ([unipole_multipole.pdf](http://intra.lemo.ch/catalog/ROW/UK_English/unipole_multipole.pdf)), I found several combinations appear to be missing. For example:

5B-304 (4 pins, size 5B) is a special order straight-pin PCB alternative, but a 5B-304 pattern is not found in the drilling pattern section (p. 154), and is not listed in the pin length tables on p. 157. However, 2B-332 (32 pins, size 2B) is also special order for PCB pins, but has a PCB drilling pattern provided.

Are there some combinations of size and contact count that need to be requested specially from Lemo, or are they obsolete and no longer manufactured?

Answer (score 1):

They're huge 4mm diameter 35A contacts.. I would guess well necked down at the PCB end, and probably rarely requested. Your Lemo rep should be able to tell you all about them (and for their prices, should give you lots of time).